# jquery having issue with global variable inside function ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is the code:

```
var ret;
function fetch_data(param1){
  $.post(param1,
        function(data){
          if (data){
            ret = data*2;
            console.log("data", ret);
          }
          else{
            ret = 15;
            console.log("no data")
          }
        });
  return ret;
}

function hello(){
  ret = fetch_data("/post_data");
  console.log("from the main function", ret);
}
```

The above is a simplified schema of how i am working with things. 
i make a post request to a url and try to get the value, based on the returned value i manipulate the value and try returning it back to the function. 
The `console.log` shows a value inside the `fetch_data` function, but not within the `hello` function. Meaning no value is returned. Where am i getting it wrong?

Answer (score 4):

After your javascript makes the initial ajax call the execution of the script proceeds to the return statement.  At this point the response to your request has not been returned yet, therefore your callback function has not executed, meaning ret has not been assigned a value.  You need to include the call to hello within your callback function in order to guarantee that ret has been assigned a value.

```
  var ret;
    function fetch_data(param1){
      $.post(param1,
            function(data){
              if (data){
                ret = data*2;
                console.log("data", ret);
              }
              else{
                ret = 15;
                console.log("no data")
              }
              hello();
            });
    }

function hello(){
  ret = fetch_data("/post_data");
  console.log("from the main function", ret);
}
```

There are two ways that Ajax can access the server. These are synchronous (wnere the script stops and waits for the server to send back a reply before continuing) and asynchronous (where the script allows the page to continue to be processed and will handle the reply if and when it arrives).  Your function is performing asynchromnously, meaning the fetch_data function is executing the return statement before the ajax call is completed.

Order of Events:

1. fetch_data is called
2. fetch_data fires off ajax request.
3. fetch data returns ret(undefined)
4. hello function prints ret to console
5. ajax response is received from server
6. ret is assigned a value based upon ajax response

I would like to further suggest that you modify your code to what I consider to be a better approach.  I believe this approach captures your intent better than specifying the hello function within your callback.

```
    function fetch_data(param1,callback){
      $.post(param1,
            function(data){
              callback(data);
            });
    }

function hello(data){
    if (data){
       ret = data*2;
       console.log("data", ret);
     }
     else{
       ret = 15;
       console.log("no data")
     }
  console.log("from the main function", ret);
}

function hello2(data){
  //...different logic that modifies data
  console.log("from the main function", ret);
}

//Function call passing the hello function as a parameter
fetch_data('/post_data', hello);

//Function call that passes hello2 function as a parameter
fetch_data('/post_data', hello2);
```

Comment: wwell thanks, for the detailed info, i could partially get you. as for me, i have to call the `fetch_data` function multiple times from within `hello` to get multiple things and manipulate the data. Hence is there any alternative out there.

Comment: are the data manipulations the same each time?  I think the second version of the code posted in my answer would handle this you just need to pass the callback

Comment: no, they are different based on multiple ifs and stuff. also i am rendering the page html via these javascript values.

Comment: ok i updated the answer to account for this.  I understand you want to process these statements similar to how you would in java, for example you query the database and assign it to a variable and then in the next line you start using your variable.  I do not believe you will be able to achieve this type of code structure given the asynchronous nature of the call.  But then again, I don't know it all, someone with more skills could prove me wrong.

Comment: thanks for giving it time. you are almost there. I will broadly tell what i am doing. there is `function A` which calls, upon the callback of `functionA` i get some values with those values param1, param2. with param1, param2  i call `function B` this function returns some value. With the returned value i call third function which generates the html. seems i have made it complicated but this is what i have done.