# JavaScript function returns before JSON result arrives

Tags: jquery

```
function GetId() {
    var id;    
    $.post("/Edit/CreateId", function (data) {
        id = data;
    });    
    return id;
}
```

But it returns before the id comes back from the server; so id is undefined.

Is there any workaround this?

Comment: Use `$.ajax()` `success` method.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155503/jquery-having-issue-with-global-variable-inside-function-ajax-function/10155553#10155553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass in a callback or use an anonymous function. It could work, but will probably be a little inconvenient. I don't know how your other functions work together though.

```
function GetId(callback) { 
    $.post("/Edit/CreateId", function (data) {
        var id = data;
        callback(id)
    });    
}
```

Example usage with anonymous function:

```
GetId(function(id){
    //Do what you need to do.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `post()` method is asynchronous and as such its `success` method will fire, when the result is there and not block the rest of the `GetId` function until then.

To get your (probably) desired behavior you can either assign the `id` value to a global variable (bad choice) or pass in the rest of the functionality as a callback function (with the `id` as an argument) directly to the `post` `success` function:

```
function GetId( cb ) { 
    $.post("/Edit/CreateId", function (data) {

        // rest of your program logic will be executed here
        cb( data );

    });    
}
```